# What is a straightforward way to implement background blur on Zoom calls for Linux?

Tags: video, camera

I've been trying to blur my background for a while for Zoom meetings. I've come across several packages that should be able to do that but I haven't had any luck so far!

- I was told [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) would be able to do it, but couldn't figure out how.
- I was told [this package](https://github.com/fangfufu/Linux-Fake-Background-Webcam) does it, but I simply could not understand how to get it started
- [This package](https://snapcraft.io/install/fakecam/arch) also failed for me even though I followed the instructions to the letter.

It's hard for me to believe that there isn't yet a "solid" solution for this yet. Does anyone have a recommendation?

Related: [Webcam effects on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580276/webcam-effects-on-linux/623531#623531)

Comment: I'm in exactly the same quest as you. What's your distribution and version? For the `fakecam` snap app, did you grant webcam use permission for the app after the installation? The command to do it from terminal: `sudo snap connect fakecam:camera`. It works, but is very CPU intensive...

Comment: In the end I was able to run it, but it definitely took a few iterations. You can find the complete issue here: https://github.com/RazZziel/fakecam/issues/2
Other than what's there I can't help you much unfortunately